# Переименовать проект в Unity, чтобы проект не был новым приложением, а обновлением

Tags: android, unity3d, update, project

Моя игра на андроид - тупо пародия на ФНаФ, но назвал я приложение по другому, чтобы друг, для которого я разрабатывал игру, думал, что это какое-то левое приложение, а там - игра по фнаф. В игре есть сохранение прогресса, т. е., PlayerPrefs используется. Теперь, когда друг прошёл игру, мне захотелось выпустить обновление, где название становится нормальным. Но при изменении имени через Настройки Проекта > Игрок > Название проекта (не помню точный путь) при скачивании apk файла игры скачиввется новое приложение, а не обновляется старое. И в итоге у меня две игры с разными названиями. Как изменить название, чтобы файл стал обновлением, а не новым приложением?

**Кому лень читать: как изменить название проекта, чтобы созданный apk файл был обновлением к предыдущему,а не новым приложением?**

Comment: Все что вам нужно, это сохранить packageName: https://forum.unity.com/threads/where-is-package-name-setting.318839/

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вы действительно мне помогли. После изменения имени проекта открылось второе дыхание, так что в этот же день исправил баги, переработал некоторые элементы, изменил баланс, добавил новый элемент геймплея и сделал порт на пк. Вы меня замотивировали. Спасибо огромное. Никогда не думал, что 7 слов, 2 знака препинания и одна ссылка способны на многое. Удачи вам)